# JSON.stringify(array) from jsp to servlet (loop using javax.json-api1.0. jar or javax.json-1.0.jar only)

Tags: java, json, servlets, jar

HTML :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" value="flag1" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="orange" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="1.00" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="5" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" value="flag2" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="apple" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="2.00" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="5" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS :

```
var array = $.map($('table tr'), function (val, i) {
    var obj = {}, inputs = $(val).find('td input:not(:hidden)');
    obj[inputs.filter(':first').val()] = $.map(inputs.not(':first'), function (val, i) {
        return val.value;
    });
    return obj;
});

alert(JSON.stringify(array));
$(document).on("click","#save",function(){
    $.post("servlet.html","data="+JSON.stringify(array)+"",function(response){
    });
});
```

Java servlet contains this :

```
 String data = request.getParameter("data");
```

data looks like this :

```
[{"flag1":["orange","1.00","5"]},{"flag2":["apple","2.00","5"]}]//this is get from table row data using stringify
```

i want to get on first loop using `javax.json-api1.0.jar` or `javax.json-1.0.jar` only :

on first loop :

```
 flag1
 Orange
 1.00
 5
```

on second loop :

```
flag2
Apple
2.00
5
```

Any help will be best.

Comment: please show us what you have tired for serverside code to manipulate the json string.

Comment: @sunleo my code only in java servlet is ` String data = request.getParameter("data");` . havent tried anything using those libraries. Im new to json so classes on that is very new to me.sorry.

Comment: please check this link   http://www.programmingforliving.com/2013/07/java-api-for-json-processing-jee7-p1.html

Comment: take a look at the apidocs: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonReader.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with only json-api, but **you** must be sure of the structure of the input data.
If not, gson or jackson2 are easier to use.

If you want to use json-api, you could do something like :

First declare a `JsonFactoryReader` attribute in your servlet because you will create a reader per request.

```
JsonReaderFactory readerFactory = Json.createReaderFactory(null);
```

then in your `service` or `doXXX` method do :

```
String data = request.getParameter("data");
// create a reader for json data
JsonReader jr = readerFactory.createReader(new StringReader(data));
// tol level must be an array, and we count the iteration for eventual error messages
JsonArray ja = jr.readArray();
int iteration = 0;
for (JsonValue jv: ja) {
    // sub elements must be dicts
    if (jv.getValueType() != ValueType.OBJECT) {
        throw new FormatException(iteration, jv);
    }
    for (Entry<String, JsonValue> e: ((JsonObject) jv).entrySet()) {
        // the key
        String key = e.getKey();
        if (e.getValue().getValueType() != ValueType.ARRAY) {
            throw new FormatException(iteration, e.getValue());
        }
        // the values, first is a string
        JsonArray array = (JsonArray) e.getValue();
        for (int i=0; i<array.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(array.get(0).getValueType());
        }
        String name = array.getString(0);
        // next a float and an int
        float fval;
        int ival;
        try {
            fval = Float.valueOf(array.getString(1));
            ival = Integer.valueOf(array.getString(2));
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            throw new FormatException(iteration, array);
        }
        // Do your stuff with those values ...
        // for instance Data data = new Data(key, name, fval, ival) ...
        iteration++;
    }
}
```

I propose you an exception class to *handle* format errors (at least you know why it breaked ...):

```
class FormatException extends ServletException {
    FormatException(int i, JsonValue jv) {
        super("Iteration " + String.valueOf(i) + " : " + jv.toString());
    }
}
```